# System Crashing when changing display order

Tags: display, 22.04

I did a fresh upgrade from 20.04 through 21.10, to 22.04 today.  Now when I change my screen order the system crashes and makes me log in again.

Any ideas how to debug this?

Some more details as I find them:

- Running wayland

```
$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
wayland
```

Doesn't fix the actual problem, but switching back to Xorg fixes the issue.  Leaving this open for now in case people run in to the same problem.

Comment: I upgraded through 21.10 to 22.04.  Updating now

Comment: Doesn't answer to the question of course, but upgrading directly from 20.04 to 22.04 would have been a better idea.

Comment: Agreed @NovHak, but that isn't available until August and I needed some software that wasn't available in in 20.04

Comment: Ah, I thought it was available upon release, but that makes sense.